# Encrypt data in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-admin-sdk

I am developing a web app using Firebase, in which teachers can create an assignment and student can submit files in that assignment. I want to implement a password feature where the teacher will be able to set a password while creating assignment and students only who know the password will be able to submit.

I have thought of implementing this feature in the following way:

When teacher will set the password, I will send the password to a **Firebase cloud function** which will encrypt the password and store it in the **Firebase real-time database** using **Firebase Admin SDK**. When students will submit the password, the password will be sent to a cloud function which will decrypt the actual encrypted password (which is stored in the real-time database), match it with the password sent from the client and send a response to the client containing a message which will tell the user if the password is matched or not.

I have four questions.

1. Will this way (described above) be secure enough?
2. If this way is secure, then how should I encrypt the password? Is there any library function to encrypt data in Firebase cloud functions? Or should I use my own encryption algorithm?
3. Is storing the encrypted password in Firebase real-time database secured? If not, then where should I store it?
4. If this way is not secured, then how can I implement the feature described above?